# Symfony - Validation: The type of the attribute must be bool, string given

Tags: symfony, validation, assert

I have an entity and a column with type boolean

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $isActive;
```

When I try to add a string to this column (just to test) I get this error message

```
The type of the attribute must be bool, string given
```

So, I add the validation type

```
* @Assert\Type(
*     type="boolean",
*     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
* )
```

but always the message error launched, so, I try the second solution by creating my own Asset validation

```
if(false === is_bool($user->getIsActive())){
   $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->atPath('isActive')->addViolation();
}
```

but always the code crushed and the message appears.

PS: if I change the column type to string the validation work correctly, but I want to use the bool type with validation, is there any solution?

Comment: That looks like a `TypeError`, not a validation error. How are you testing this? Instancing an object and calling `setActive()` or via a form?

Comment: @msg via a form

Comment: @msg Honestly I use Api plateform, so when I post a new user

Comment: This issue relates to API plateforms configuration, not to symfony validaiton.
See a similar question here: https://github.com/api-platform/admin/issues/179

Comment: What value do you send to your API ?

Comment: @Smaïne I send an incorrect value, like a string or integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding this line :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     denormalizationContext={
 *        "disable_type_enforcement"=true
 *     }
 * )
 */
```